# Algebra percentage question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sixteen and two thirds percent of x equals 3.2 what is x?

Can anyone help me solve this my final answer I get is forty eight over two hundred fifty but I am not sure if this is correct?

Comment: Use a calculator

Comment: If 16% of x is 3.2, would you expect x to be greater or less than 3.2?

Comment: Can you express sixteen and two thirds percent as a fraction?

Comment: yes it is 50/3 is the fraction.

Comment: Percent ($\%$) means divided by $100$. So it is a funny way to refer to the fraction $\frac{\frac{50}{3}}{100}$. This simplifies to $1/6$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $16\frac 23 \%=\frac {50}3 \cdot \frac 1{100}=\frac 16$

Comment: hmm how would I utilize this 1/6 to solve the problem?never mind solved it. I got my answer as x=19.2 once I set the 1/6x=3.2

Comment: Write your equation as $\frac 16 x = 3.2$ and solve.  As the percentage is less than $100\%$ you should expect that $x \gt 3.2$ which your original solution is not.

Comment: Thank you for the hint it took me a second to figure it out.